# How to receive moveEvent() in the middle of moving for top-level QWidget?

Tags: qt, qt6

I'm trying to implement Qt based application with `Qt::WindowTransparentForInput` and internal control that can be clicked. Ok, the protopype is so:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow()
    :   QWidget( nullptr, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::WindowDoesNotAcceptFocus |
                 Qt::WindowTransparentForInput )
{
    setWindowTitle( tr( "GIF Recorder" ) );
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true );

    m_w = new QWidget( nullptr, Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint | Qt::CustomizeWindowHint );
    auto vlayout = new QVBoxLayout( m_w );
    vlayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    auto layout = new QHBoxLayout;
    layout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    auto button = new QToolButton( this );
    button->setText( tr( "Record" ) );
    layout->addWidget( button );
    layout->addItem( new QSpacerItem( 10, 0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed ) );
    vlayout->addLayout( layout );
    vlayout->addItem( new QSpacerItem( 0, 0, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Expanding ) );
    m_w->setSizePolicy( QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed );
    m_w->resize( 800, button->sizeHint().height() );
    m_w->move( geometry().x(), geometry().y() );
    m_w->show();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete m_w;
}

void
MainWindow::moveEvent( QMoveEvent * e )
{
    m_w->move( geometry().x(), geometry().y() );

    e->accept();
}

void
MainWindow::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * e )
{
    m_w->resize( e->size().width(), m_w->height() );

    e->accept();
}

void
MainWindow::closeEvent( QCloseEvent * e )
{
    m_w->close();

    e->accept();
}
```

All is fine except one problem. When I move the `MainWindow` with mouse on clicking windows' title, the `MainWindow` receive only one `moveEvent()` when mouse is released.

Is it possible to receive `moveEvent()` for top-level widget in the middle of moving, when mouse button is pressed and not released yet?

I see that in:

```cpp
bool
MainWindow::nativeEvent( const QByteArray & eventType, void * message, qintptr * result )
{
    static int i = 0;
    qDebug() << eventType << ++i;
    return false;
}
```

There are no middle native events between starting moving and finish. So I believe that there is no solution for my question, but maybe somebody know how to implement Qt based window transparent for input but with some region in it with handling events?

One clarification - I'm on Linux.

I have an idea to refuse totally from windows manager title bar and implement custom frameless widget with some mask set on it. Need to check it...

Answer (score 0):

In case of subject (title) on Linux the answer - it's impossible.

But in case with different approach to make a such GUI, `setMask()` works.

So the prototype of the UI (just a proof of concept) is so:

```cpp
MainWindow::MainWindow()
    :   QWidget( nullptr, Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnTopHint )
{
    setAttribute( Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground );

    auto vlayout = new QVBoxLayout( this );
    vlayout->setContentsMargins( 0, 0, 0, 0 );
    m_title = new QWidget( this );
    m_title->setAutoFillBackground( true );
    auto layout = new QHBoxLayout( m_title );
    layout->setContentsMargins( 5, 5, 5, 0 );
    m_recordButton = new QToolButton( m_title );
    m_recordButton->setText( tr( "Record" ) );
    layout->addWidget( m_recordButton );
    layout->addItem( new QSpacerItem( 10, 0, QSizePolicy::Expanding, QSizePolicy::Fixed ) );

    vlayout->addWidget( m_title );
    vlayout->addItem( new QSpacerItem( 0, 0, QSizePolicy::Fixed, QSizePolicy::Expanding ) );
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
}

void
MainWindow::resizeEvent( QResizeEvent * e )
{
    m_mask = QBitmap( e->size().width(), e->size().height() );

    QPainter p( &m_mask );
    p.setBrush( Qt::color1 );
    p.setPen( Qt::color1 );
    p.drawRect( rect() );
    p.setPen( Qt::color0 );
    p.setBrush( Qt::color0 );
    const auto xy = m_title->rect().bottomLeft() + QPoint( 5, 5 );
    p.drawRect( xy.x(), xy.y(), width() - 10, height() - m_title->rect().height() - 10 );

    setMask( m_mask );

    e->accept();
}

void
MainWindow::paintEvent( QPaintEvent * )
{
    QPainter p( this );
    p.setPen( palette().color( QPalette::Window ) );
    p.setBrush( palette().brush( QPalette::Window ) );

    p.drawRect( rect() );
}
```

Checked both on Linux and Windows.